# Analytical solution to density dependent system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know if there is an analytical solution to the following system of density-dependent ODEs, for $i = 1,...,S$?

$$\dot{x_i} = \frac{ \pi x_i}{K + \sum_{j=1}^S (x_j+y_j)} - \delta x_i + \varepsilon_i y_i - sx_i  \\
\dot{y_i} = \frac{ p y_i}{K + \sum_{j=1}^S (x_j+y_j)} - d y_i - \varepsilon_i y_i + sx_i
$$

where $\pi, \delta, p, d, K, \varepsilon_i$ and $s$ are all constants ($\forall i$).

Any help (even to tell me that no such solution exists) would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try mathematica?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't - I don't have it and don't speak it. I'll look into that. Thank you